# Bigquery: STRUCT (*) syntax

Tags: struct, google-bigquery, except

How can I automatically apply `STRUCT` to all fields in a table without specifying them by name?

Example that does not work:

```
WITH data as (
 SELECT 'Alex' as name, 14 as age, 'something else 1' other_field
UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'Bert' as name, 14 as age, 'something else 2' other_field
UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'Chiara' as name, 13 as age, 'something else 3' other_field
)

SELECT AS STRUCT(SELECT * except (other_field) from data) as student_data
```

Returns: `Error: Scalar subquery cannot have more than one column unless using SELECT AS STRUCT to build STRUCT values at [9:17]`

This however works:

```
WITH data as (
 SELECT 'Alex' as name, 14 as age, 'something else 1' other_field
UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'Bert' as name, 14 as age, 'something else 2' other_field
UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'Chiara' as name, 13 as age, 'something else 3' other_field
)

SELECT STRUCT(name,age) as student_data

from data
```

The problem is that once I have 100 columns where only 5 don't belong, it makes me crazy to write them out. Is there a simpler way to use some version of `Select * Except()`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 'Alex' AS name, 14 AS age, 'something else 1' other_field UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'Bert' AS name, 14 AS age, 'something else 2' other_field UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'Chiara' AS name, 13 AS age, 'something else 3' other_field
)
SELECT (
  SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(other_field)
  FROM UNNEST([t])
  ) AS student_data
FROM data t
```

with output

```
Row student_data.name   student_data.age     
1   Alex                14   
2   Bert                14   
3   Chiara              13
```

Comment: This is great! Where an I find documentation on this notation for `UNNEST([t])`?

Comment: Please note that you might need to wrap the SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(other_field) in (). The UNNEST([t]) part is not required. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65302901/413531 for the full example.

Comment: @Hirnhamster - this is obviously wrong statement - just try both solutions and you will see why! :o)

Answer (score 4):

As update to Mikhail Berlyant's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60265292/413531 because the comment section doesn't let me use proper formatting:

Please note that you might need to wrap the `SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(other_field)` in (). The UNNEST([t]) part is not required. I.e. this also works:

```
#standardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 'Alex' AS name, 14 AS age, 'something else 1' other_field UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'Bert' AS name, 14 AS age, 'something else 2' other_field UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'Chiara' AS name, 13 AS age, 'something else 3' other_field
)
SELECT
  (SELECT AS STRUCT data.* EXCEPT(other_field)) as student_data,
FROM data
```

[image: no unnest]

---

[image]

Comment: see comments in answer you referenced :o)

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to? Unless you mean the duplicate "name" - that slipped somehow in :)

Answer (score 2):

You need an expression for the `AS STRUCT expr`

```
SELECT AS STRUCT data.* except (other_field) from data
```